# Python pygame mac import

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, import, pygame

I installed pygame from `pygame-1.9.1release-python.org-32bit-py2.7-macosx10.3.dmg`. I have Python 2.7.6 and OSX 10.9.2. For some reason, when I do the following I get an `ImportError`:

```
>>> import pygame

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
    from pygame.base import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/base.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/base.so: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
```

How can I get pygame to work? And is there a way to get pygame for Python 3.4? I currently have both Python 2.7.6 and Python 3.4 installed.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try using [Macports](https://www.macports.org/) to install pygame. That package that you installed was for version OSX 10.3 which used PowerPC architecture whereas you are running OSX 10.9 which uses Intel.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install a 32 bit version of Python.  PyGame doesn't run on the 64 bit builds, and OSX ships with a 64 bit build.

When I was working with PyGame it was the sole reason I installed 32 bit Python.  I wish they would work on 64 bit support more.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second question, no, they only have pygame available for python 2.7.  But for your first question, I don't know if this would work, but try using

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import*
pygame.init()
```

That is what I need to initialize my pygame, so maybe it will work.